# Clojure / Lein / Package into Jar

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen

For the past 6 months, I have been running my Clojure app from the repl.

I.e., whenever I want to run the app, I load up a clojure repl, then I type in:
(load-file "src/run.clj") ... and it runs my app.

Then, clojure loads up all of my *.clj files, compiles them, and runs.

I have recently switched over to Lein. I would like to "compile ahead of time / package up" my code, so that I can get a single jar, with Main method, and run it directly on the command line via "java ..." rather than having to load up a clojure/lein repl.

It's clear to me that I need to do some RTFMing. However, if someone could point me at a good tutorial, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There is also a nice tutorial in the [official lein tutorial](https://codeberg.org/leiningen/leiningen/src/branch/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md). I'm just including this information in case we end up with any dead links in the future.

1. You first need to designate the main namespace by adding `:main` to project.clj

   (defproject yourproject "0.1"
   :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]]
   :main yourproject.core)
2. In your designated main namespace you must add `(:gen-class)` and you must designate the main function by using `(defn -main ...)`

   (ns yourproject.core
   (:gen-class))

   (defn -main [& args]
   (println "This is your crazy project!"))
3. run `uberjar` to create the standalone jar

   lein uberjar
4. run your program with `java -jar`

   java -jar yourproject.jar